# TextView Font Size is not according to Device Font Size Settings

Tags: android, fonts, font-size, text-size

I have an application where TextView sizes are mentioned in '**sp**'.

```
android:textSize=”30sp”
```

But If I change the Device Font sizes, Applied Device Font Size is not reflecting in the Application. What might be the issue for it. I have not written any code for restricting the Device Font Size in the Application

```
settings > display > font = small/normal/large/huge
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the text size in java file 
put following method in javafile

```
private int dpToPx(int dp)
    {
        return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
```

then try this code.

```
 name = (Textview) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    int textsize= dptopx(30);
    name.setTextSize(textsize);
```